# Gcp support binding service account from firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, function, google-cloud-platform

Im hosting a webapp in firebase(angular), who's triggering some functions in Google cloud functions, for some reason of security, we probably call this functions with a register service account, the question is, the angular should contain this service account (json file), to validate in front of gcp ?

maybe is just a good practica use a single token, per user who call the API/FUNCTION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely should **not** include service accounts in your web and mobile apps.  That's a huge security hole.  Service accounts are meant to authenticate secure backend-to-backed communications.  Putting one into the public is basically saying that you want anyone to be able to invoke your function at any time (and potentially do anything else that account is authorized to do).

Instead, you should be using [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) to identify your users, and authorize them to make use of your backend functions.  You can use the Firebase Admin SDK to [verify that a function is being invoked by a registered user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), and that the user has the permission necessary to invoke it.

Comment: That's is what im trying to confirm, so we keep using Firebase Admin SDK